# I have two dataframes. I wanted to compare header of one dataframe with the content of one column in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Have two dataframes. I the first dataframe there is a column name testname in which I have 88 test and in second dataframe I made those test name as header. So now I want to compare the content of testname column which is in first dataframe with the header of second dataframe. I wanted to check for each id in first dataframe if the testname is available I want to add that particular testname value in second dataframe.

I have tried it by iterating both the dataframes and and the first step is also done that is matching of ids but I don't know how to compare content and header at the same time

Comment: Please provide a sample of each dataframe that shows an example of what you're trying to interact with? Feel free to change the contents if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Follows my solution based on how I understood the problem statement:

```
import pandas as pd

#Creating Data Frames
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'testname':['88test', 'nonono', '88test'],
               'col2': [1, 2, 3],
               'col3': [4, 5, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'88test':[9, 10], 'col4':[11, 12]})

#Selecting rows and column of interest from df1
df1_selected_rows = df1[['testname']][df1['testname']=='88test']
df1_selected_rows.rename(columns={'testname':'88test'}, inplace=True)

#Merging data of interest into df2 using pandas.merge()
pd.merge(df2, df1_selected_rows, how='outer')

#The same can be achieved using pandas.concat(), but preserving the original indexes of both dataframes
pd.concat(objs=[df2,df1_selected_rows], sort=False)
```